# Package Python 3 executable that does not require programming knowledge

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, cx-freeze, pythonw

I would like to send my Python3 script to my father-in-law and grandmother. Each has their own Windows machine, one is running Windows 7 and the other is running XP.

Not sure how to package it up for them to run on their respective machines. Is there such a method?

My script prompts, while in the IDE environment, for Keyword, path, filename. So there are some inputs, the user has to type in. Not sure if that will affect the portable script creation.

After reading through some responses here on StackOverFlow, I found `py2exe` does not work with Python 3.

Also `Pytonw`, suggested here as well,  looks very complicated. I don't think either of my relative could carry out those steps.

Lastly `CX-Freeze` site I get ublock filters-Badware risks and a big warning window when I visit their website.

Comment: I belive the best approach here is to install python3.4 for Windows on their machines. It is as easy as run "msi" (or "exe") file. After it, you may send them ".bat" file like ```c:\python34\python.exe your_script.py``` and they run it.

Comment: ublock defaults to blocking everything on Sourceforge, which is a bit over aggressive - Sourceforge does some scummy stuff, but there's also quite a lot of valuable projects still on it. You can find cx_Freeze [docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and [downloads](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/) on separate sites, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used cx-freeze to deploy python apps compiled to windows .exe files for us by computer novice users for several years and it has worked well.  you will occasionally run into issues with dependencies you will have to take extra steps for (Datetime for example) but nothing that isn't surmountable.  The easiest way to handle it is to install the folder on the computer yourself and create a desktop shortcut to it for the user.  That keeps it simple for them.  If you are not close to them you can always use a program like team viewer to gain access to their computer like remote desktop.

Comment: Thank you trapspring will investigate. This will lead to some interesting steps as they do not have TeamView. They live about 2K miles away and are  running AOL dial up.

Comment: what version of Python and cx-freeze are you running everything I find says it works with Python 2.x not 3.cx Freeze

Comment: I use 3.2 and 3.3 and cx_freeze has been working great

Comment: Since we last talked got py2exe to work on Python 3 programs, placed them on a USB stick, tried them on my vista machine and worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you all unfortunately both have passed since then. Thank you for your help.